# Stability of ODE involving trig functions and nonhyperbolic fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Consider the following autonomous vector field:

$$\dot x = −x$$

$$\dot y = \sin y$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2, -\pi ≤ y ≤ \pi$

$\bullet$ Find all fixed points.

$\bullet$ Determine the linearized stability properties of each fixed point.

$\bullet$ Determine the global stable and unstable manifolds of the origin.

$\bullet$ Determine whether any nonhyperbolic fixed points are stable or unstable? (You must justify your answer.)

**ATTEMPT**:

$\bullet$ Fixed points: $(0, -\pi), (0,0), (0,\pi)$

$\bullet$ Linearisation by the Jacobian:

$J = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos y \end{pmatrix}$

So we have:

$J(0,-\pi) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, 
$J(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$,
 $J(0,\pi) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$

Which represent a sink (stable), a saddle (unstable), and a sink (stable) respectively,

$\bullet$ For the global stable manifold we can see by simply solving for $x$:

$\dot x = -x \Rightarrow  \int \frac{\dot x}{x} dt = \int \frac{dx}{x} = -\int dt$

$\Rightarrow x = e^{-t+c}$

Using $x(0) = x_0$ an arbitrary initial condition $\Rightarrow x_0 = e^c$

$x = x_0 e^{-t}$ is the global stable manifold as $x \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ for all initial conditions

My problem here is with the unstable manifold due to the $\sin$ function and that there doesn't seem to be any nonhyperbolic fixed points, as I have two sinks and a saddle? I feel like that the unstable manifold should simply be the region $-\pi \le y \le \pi$ but I just wanted clarification.

As far as I am taught, the saddle points is hyperbolic so I'm not sure where the nonhyperbolic fixed points come from, unless I am missing something obvious or have done something wrong.

Comment: You're right, all fixed points are hyperbolic.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you, I'm not really sure why this question is asked other than to say that there are no hyperbolic fixed points. Are you able to shed any light on my thoughts for the unstable manifold?

Comment: The origin is a saddle, so the unstable manifold is just a curve, not a whole two-dimensional region like $|y| \le \pi$. But if you change to strict inequalities and add the condition $x=0$, it should be OK.

Comment: @HansLundmark I can see why the inequalities should be strict and thus $-\pi \lt y \lt \pi$ but why must $x = 0$ for the unstable manifold when $\dot y$ oscillates?

Comment: The unstable manifold consists of the points from which you approach the origin if you run time backwards. But in backwards time, you move *away* (exponentially!) from the $x$-axis unless you are exactly *on* the $x$-axis to begin with.